# Test React component with imported functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a component where inside `useEffect` hook calls a function that is imported from another file.

How I can mock this function in tests?

Also, how can I check that `useEffect` is called in the component?

Minimal code:

```
//utils.js
export const doSomething = async () => {
   return await fetch('url')
}
//Component.js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {CardImg} from 'reactstrap';
import {doSomething} from "../../services/utils";

const Component = ({type}) => {
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        doSomething(type)
           .then(res => setAnswer(res))

    }, [type]);

    if (!answer) {
        return <span>Loading ...</span>;
    }
    return <span>{answer}</span>
};

export default Component;
```

Comment: What lib you are using to write your tests? are you using Jest?

Comment: yes Jest and Enzyme

Comment: it was closed by stack overflow, but what you need to do is to `mount` the component, do not use `shallow`, if you use `shallow` it will not run the `useEffect`.